# How to use Spring Cloud Dataflow to get Spring Batch Status

Tags: spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-batch-admin

I have been using Spring Batch and my metadata is in DB2. I have been using Spring Batch admin API (jars) to look at the current status of various jobs and getting details about job, like number of items read, commit count, etc. Now, since Spring Batch Admin is moved to spring-data-cloud, how do look at these informations? Is there a good API set I could use?

Comment: I don't really understand what your actual question is... can you pls rephrase and provide additional info... maybe some links? or what is missing...

Answer (score 0):

Basically, in Spring Cloud Data flow, you first need to create Spring Cloud Task that will have your Batch application: See example `[here][1]`

With the help of Spring Cloud @EnableTaskLauncher you can get the current status of job, run the job, stop the job, etc.

You need to send [TasKLauncherRequest](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-task/blob/master/spring-cloud-task-stream/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/task/launcher/TaskLaunchRequest.java) for it.
See APIs of [TaskLauncher](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-deployer/blob/master/spring-cloud-deployer-spi/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/deployer/spi/task/TaskLauncher.java)

Edition:

To get spring batch status, u need to have first Task execution id of spring cloud task. `Set<Long> getJobExecutionIdsByTaskExecutionId(long taskExecutionId);` method of `[TaskExplorer][3]`

See Task Explorer for all the apis. With it, use [JobExplorer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/explore/JobExplorer.html) to get status of jobs